# Power BI - How to create another table from original source

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I wrote a query that pulls data into Power BI. I was wondering if I can create another query that pulls in the original data without certain columns. I know that I can delete a column but I was wondering if I can remove a column and have other columns aggregated. I want to do this from the back-end (PowerQuery). I know I can create another query without including the other column but since this is real-time data, I need to pull the data from the original query.

This is the original data.

[image]

This is what I am trying to achieve. I want to remove the column 'Code' but as well as having the other columns aggregated (Calls, Invalid) and distinct columns (Date, Name, Connection Type).

[image]

Is this possible on the power query?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible. Here is an example M code how to do that in Power Query:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("ndKxCoMwEAbgd8ksohdN5y527VDoIA5BQwnYCufSx28oKZHmzqQdJEL4uPvv0vcCoDyUUEElCnExT726s3bf1aKZ3Hm8G7Sjdn/yfTMUtAHSNKQ5mQVvVrOV2oT6r5b0ajbrmlHurNF+B+tQP0bj++aJzCfdvKCdtqGi9iAB2Vz0wgJsyDFu+qz5pxEV22dsuH0myQ4lacKi2x9yBaVIBaSKt5bTYbwy9tmT6pMrGqJKQMVBP5PhBQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Date = _t, Name = _t, Code = _t, #"Connection Type" = _t, Country = _t, Calls = _t, Invalid = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Name", type text}, {"Code", type text}, {"Connection Type", type text}, {"Country", type text}, {"Calls", Int64.Type}, {"Invalid", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Code"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Date", "Name", "Connection Type", "Country"}, {{"Calls", each List.Sum([Calls]), type text}, {"Invalid", each List.Sum([Invalid]), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

`Table.RemoveColumns` will remove the `Code` column and `Table.Group` will group the data on the specified columns (`Date`, `Name`, `Connection Type` and `Country`) and aggregate the data, sum in this case (`Calls` and `Invalid`).

You can do this using the UI only. In Power Query Editor, right click the title of `Code` column and select `Remove`. Then from `Transform` tab click on the leftmost button `Group By` and fill it as follows:

[image]